# Customise FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I currently have a Full Calendar displayed on my page to show when certain people are on Holiday or off Sick. However, instead of showing as a bar spread across the days, i would like to have the persons initials displayed on the day in question. Does anybody have any idea about how i may go about this?

My current code is:

```
function initialiseCalendar(data) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: data,
            weekends: false,
            theme: false,
            height:600,
            eventLimit: true,
            eventClick: function (event) {
                window.open(event.url);
                return false;
            },
            eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
                var startdate = event.start._i;
                var timeindex = startdate.indexOf("T");
                var startsub = startdate.substring(timeindex + 1, timeindex + 3);
                if (startsub == "12") {
                    var e = $('a[href="' + event.url + '"')
                    e.css('margin-left', '100px');
                }
                var enddate = event.end._i;
                var index = enddate.indexOf("T");
                var endsub = enddate.substring(index + 1, index + 3);
                if (endsub == "12") {
                    var e = $('a[href="' + event.url + '"')
                    e.css('margin-right', '100px');
                }
            },
            header: {
                left: 'title',
                center: '',
                right: 'today prev,next month basicWeek basicDay'
            }
        });
    }
```

I am also open to using alternate plugins if there is one which would allow this.

Thanks

Comment: Create one separate event per day for each of the people on vacation, and set the event background to transparent? Alternatively, create an event with a special colour for each day, and set the event.title to the initials of all people on vacation on that day.

Comment: I was hoping to have it so that no bars are displayed, but with initials inside a coloured circle